# How to run jQuery only on non-mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I'm using this jQuery for an (excellent) lightbox-like plugin called [zoombox](http://grafikart.github.io/Zoombox/):

```
        $('a.zoombox').zoombox({...});
```

It takes `a` links in the form `http://vimeo.com/15171582`, parses the vimeo id (15171582) and pops up a lightbox which loads an `iframe` with this URL:

`http://player.vimeo.com/video/15171582?autoplay=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&wmode=transparent`

How can I modify the jQuery so that, when viewed on a mobile browser,

1. the lightbox doesn't launch, and
2. the simple link gets converted to the `iframe` link?

Comment: Have jQuery get the height / width of the browser and launch prevent the launch of the screen size it too small. Same thing to manipulate the link.

Comment: here you go: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Comment: [Check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ to detect mobile devices.

Or detect window width like:

```
function isMobile() {
   if(window.innerWidth <= 600) {
     return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
}
```

And make it responsive like:

```
// keep original url
$('a.zoombox').each(function() {
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).data('url',url);
});

// on load
doMagic();

// resizing
$(window).resize(function() {
  doMagic();
});

// lightbox?
function doMagic() {
  $('a.zoombox').each(function() {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    $(this).attr('href',url);
  });
  if (!isMobile) {
    $('a.zoombox').zoombox({...}); // lightbox here
  }
}

// detect mobile
function isMobile() {
  if(window.innerWidth <= 600) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

*NOT TESTED*

edit: add doMagic call on load..

Comment: Just a simplification of the isMobile() is: `return window.innerWidth <= 600;`